# How to go at a position in new activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, position

Hi friends and Developer,

How can I go at certain position in new activity?

1. for example when I pressed a button which will open Settings activity.
2. after my action Settings activity opened.
3. Now I want that Activity automatically scroll to the sounds position in settings where sounds related features are present.

how can I do this??

Answer (score 1):

[Setting provider. Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Check that out, you can modify your intent to contain the specified setting with this. ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS might be the one.

Answer (score 0):

If your Settings Activity has a ListView of items, you can use:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(indexOf(sound_item));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am not using listview. I am using LinearLayout with other nested viewgroups. And how can I tell my app  that go to the settings activity at ___ position,  when I am not settings activity. For other features position may be changed. so I want a dynamic way to approach the position...